# A few more "hundred" vs "hundreds"

Tags: numbers

If we're talking about 8 hundred (an exact number of hundreds) we use the singular for the ordinal. But what if we use an unspecified quantity such as "more". Or, I just said it: "number of hundreds". So I reckon it's "more hundreds", "more thousands". Is this correct?

Exact context:

> If you have a larger budget, feel free to go for a few more hundreds of MHz more for your CPU.

Comment: The ordinal would be *800th*; I think you mean cardinal.

Comment: Right, sorry. I got confused.

Comment: I'd suggest *buy a slightly faster CPU*. "A few hundred more MHz for your CPU" sounds like you're taking a CPU to the computer store and asking them to sprinkle on 600 MHz.

Comment: Suggestion noted and accepted. Still want to know how I should use the cardinal in the case in question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use the singular when the magnitude number is modified by *few*:

> We need a few hundred dollars.
>
> We need a few thousand widgets.

If we keep the object, we would put *more* after the number:

> We need a few hundred more dollars.
>
> We need a few thousand more widgets.

But if we drop the explicit object and go with the "few ... more" construction, the demarcation is not so clear, because the number *becomes* the object in the sentence:

> We need a few hundred more.
>
> We need a few thousand more.
>
> We need a few more hundred.
>
> We need a few more thousand.

While it is stylistically better to use the former in writing, you hear the latter case used all the time in speech, and it is readily understood. In this case, it would be misleading (or at least ambiguous) to pluralize the numbers, because it would imply that the number is an unbreakable unit. Note that the latter still considers the number to be somewhat unitary, but not rigidly so. This is an important distinction.

If you were to say

> We need a few more hundreds.

it could be construed as meaning the need was specifically for hundred-dollar bills, instead of a quantity of money that is merely in the hundreds of dollars.

But if you say

> We need a few more hundred.

you are asking the listener to consider "hundred" as a softer kind of unitary grouping.

Example from real life: When I got my current job, my salary demand was slightly higher than their range allowed. I declined the offer, but the company really wanted to hire me, so after consultations with management the company representative called me back and said, "It turns out we can come up with a few more thousand after all." He might easily have said "a few thousand more," but the way he put it put more emphasis on increments of one thousand than increments of "thousands of ones." I hope I'm making this clear, because the more I write, the finer this distinction sounds, and yet I do feel it is an important usage distinction to make and understand.

Comment: I think you nailed it pretty good with the "few more hundreds" example where you reminded me of the possibility for misunderstanding. I will go for the singular in the future, if I ever come across the "more XXX" construction again. But overall, I understand that I should avoid the construction altogether, as jwpat7 recommended.

Comment: @Axonn: there is no reason to avoid the construction altogether. If you use "few", you should use the singular, and if you use "of", you should use the plural. But this [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=few+hundred+more%2Cfew+more+hundred%2Chundreds+more+of%2Cfew+hundred+more+of%2Cfew+hundreds+more+of%2Cfew+more+hundreds+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows that none of the phrases "a few hundred more", "a few more hundred", and "hundreds more of" are uncommon.

Comment: @Peter Shor: "few more hundreds" is definitely bad ::- D. Thanks for the ngram.

Comment: I would think that "few more hundreds *of* something" would in many cases be better than "few more hundred of something", since the prepositional phrase would imply that "hundred" was being used as a noun.  Merely saying "a few more hundred" by itself could be taken as shorthand for "a few more hundred [aforementioned things]", in which case "hundred" is an adjective, but adjectives don't usually attach to prepositional phrases.  The most notable exception would be "hundred of them" [as opposed to "hundreds of them"]; in that case, I would consider "of them" to be an idiomatic construction...

Comment: ...rather than a literal prepositional phrase, since there is no other form of pronoun meaning "thing such as that".

Comment: @supercat: I think the hairs you are attempting to split are too fine for me to see.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it would help to think of how it is used. When a cardinal number is used as an adjective, it is treated as adjective in that it does not change number. There is a *red* house. There are many more *red* houses. ... *Red* does not change. There is *one* (more) house. There are five *hundred* (more) houses.

OR ... think of it as a suffix like -teen or -ty. These do not change when used as numbers: There are *seventeen* more houses. There are *sixty* more houses. There are two *hundred* (more) houses.

The *more* doesn't change anything here.

When hundred is a noun then it can be made plural. A hundred-dollar bill can be shortened to a hundred. Here it is a noun: I need two more *hundreds* (meaning 100-dollar bills).

Then there is the one that is tripping you up ... as a predeterminer/multiplier (not sure of the exact part of speech) ... I see *hundreds* (of houses). I need *hundreds* more (meaning I need *an unspecified timesing of a hundred* more). BUT ... if you know the **exact number** then becomes an adjective again without the plural ... I need 500 (five hundred) (more) houses.

The same applies to *thousand* or *million*. I need *thousands* more ... I need *millions* more.

I don't know if that helps or makes it murkier! lol

Answer (score 2):

For unknown numbers, we can use "more" with the order of magnitude as in *dozens more*, *hundreds more*, and so on.

> There are 12,000 Starbucks locations in the U.S., and *thousands more* abroad.
>
> The national debt is over $15 trillion, but the unfunded liability for Social Security is *tens of trillions more*.

Comment: So you're saying that I'm not allowed to use it in this context? "If you have a bigger budget, feel free to go for a few more hundreds of MHz more for your CPU."

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question. Placing *more* after the quantity is different from placing it before, as he did.

Comment: I thought it was clear with the examples that *more* comes after, not before.

Comment: Your version definitely sounds better and I will rephrase my text. But as far as I understood, it's acceptable to have it before, even if you lose a few points in the stylistic department.

Comment: @Axonn: Either "a few hundred MHz more" or "a few hundreds of MHz more".  If you omit "of", then "hundred" serves as an adjective and thus needs no plural prefix. If you include "of", then "hundreds" may be considered a noun and thus use a plural suffix.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either of *hundred* or *hundreds* in *...few more hundred(s)...* but would write *...few more hundred MHz...* vs *...few more hundreds* of *MHz...*
Note, the repetition of *more* in *more hundreds of MHz more* is both clumsy and unnecessary.  One instead might write any of

> ... feel free to go for a few hundreds of MHz more for your CPU.
>   ... feel free to go for a few hundred MHz more for your CPU.
>   ... feel free to go for a few more hundreds of MHz for your CPU.

For examples, see links at ngrams for triplets formed from words *few, more, hundred, hundreds, of.*  It will be seen that all of *more hundreds of, hundreds more of, few hundred more, few more hundred, few hundreds more, few more hundreds* have been used.  (Not all pairs of these triplets are comparable.)  While relative frequencies of use are interesting, it may be more useful to you to explore the source links given by [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more+hundreds+of%2Chundreds+more+of%2Cfew+hundred+more%2Cfew+more+hundred%2Cfew+hundreds+more%2Cfew+more+hundreds&year_start=1776&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=30), as for example those for 
*[more hundreds of](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22more%20hundreds%20of%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en)*.  Following the links, you can easily find and compare phrasings such as "the world might well have to wait several more hundreds of millions of years before another such goose arose" ([**BTAS**](http://books.google.com/books?id=yg0AAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA271&dq=%22more+hundreds+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ado3T4fWA6nQmAW26sj6BQ&ved=0CEQQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22more%20hundreds%20of%22&f=false), p. 271, Sep 1947).  [image: ngrams for 6 phrases]

The phrase *hundreds more of* (red line) was frequent in the 1800's, *more hundreds of* (blue line) in the early 1900's, and *few hundred more* (green line) at the moment.  Until about 1890, *few more hundred* (yellow line) and *few more hundreds* (pinkish line) were used with about the same frequency; since then, *few more hundred* has been about twice as frequent.

Comment: Oh my. Apparently I ran into a can of worms eh? ::- ). I admit that my text is a bit clumsy, I rephrased it, but still, quite a complicated issue. Also, do you trust those ngrams?

Comment: @Axonn, I know of no reason to doubt  information provided by ngrams: relative percentages of books per year containing phrases.  Of course irrelevant usages and punctuation mingled within phrases may misleadingly inflate counts.  [ngrams/info](http://books.google.com/ngrams/info) lists some of the corporae used, and mentions a journal article explaining methodology of sampling.

Comment: hm, yes, it seems pretty solid. Thank you for telling me about ngrams. I didn't know about it ::- ). Also shows that my usage is not very popular ::- ).